# Nodejs SQLite Callback Execution Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

So I understand that this is a topic that has been covered, but I am yet to find an example that demonstrates an entire implementation.

I am simply trying to make a SQLite db.get call, and return an object that I can later use.

I understand that the callback is key here, and perhaps it is because I simply don't under Javascript/async well enough, but I need to know how to access the returned object from the callback, but this has proven difficult for for me. (I am very new to JS, mostly Java background)

Take this code for example:

```
function foo(){
    db.get("SELECT open_hour, open_minut FROM autorun_open", function(err, row) {
        console.log(row.open_hour);
        console.log(row.open_minut);
        row = row.open_hour;
        callback(row);
    });
}

function callback(row) {
    console.log("R:" + row);
}
```

How can I call this function such that I can get a `row` object back from the function?

As a sort of pseudo-code example, I've tried things like this:

```
let row = foo();
   console.log("My row: " + row);
```

The issue, is that of course the execution is asynchronous, and row is always undefined.

How can I actually get a row object from this callback?

Thank you to all, and I apologize that this question is similar to others, but I have looked for every other post possible and simply can't find an example that is complete enough for me to understand.

Comment: Do you get desired output with `console.log(row.open_hour) and console.log(row.open_minut)`? or those are `undefined` as well?

Comment: Yes, I get the correct object data for both of those, as well as the **    console.log("R:" + row);** in the callback. It's just anything outside of those functions that I'm having trouble returning anything to.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you want to get `row` outside your `function foo()`.

You have to use `return` keyword to return data from a function, that's how we do in C# or java

```js
function foo(){
 let row='This is my row data'
  return callback(row);
    
}

function callback(row) {
    console.log("R:" + row);
    return row
} 


let row= foo()

console.log("My row: " + row)
```

I simplified the example a little bit, but the basic concept is you have to use `return`

**Update**

Even if you do `async/await`, you cannot get data outside function because JavaScript is single threaded and it doesn't wait for your function to get executed, All the asynchronous stuff is handled by [Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) .

*It's like saying I want to read tomorrow's newspaper today which is not possible. (PS- I read this line somewhere on SO but cant find the source)*

So long story short, you cannot get data returned by `async/await` call outside because by the time your `query` returns data. Your script would be finished running and already printed `undefined`

This is not the best example but i hope, it helps

```
function async foo(){
       let row='This is my row data'
       await callback(row);

    }

    function async callback(row) {
        console.log("R:" + row);
        await row
    } 


    let row= foo()

    console.log("My row: " + row) //<--- Still undefined because foo() is still working in background and this prints default value of undefined
```

Comment: Okay the return is of course completely correct, thank you for showing me that. The issue I still have though, is that since it's asynchronous, the console.log statement executes before foo(), so the console.log("Mry row: " + row) prints "My row: undefinted". So the issue is I need to wait until foo() has executed somehow.

Comment: Okay I see, I am not familiar with async/await. Is there any way you could update your code example to show the basic idea of how this would be implemented?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm able to explain it properly but check out the update